# How to add a single texture on a terrain in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Am new to OpenGL. Is it possible to wrap a single image on a terrain?

The below code would generate image tile , but I want to add single tile on entire terrain.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, land);
for (int z = 0; z < MAP_Z-1; z++)
{

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int x = 0; x < MAP_X-1; x++)
    {

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(terrain[x][z][0], terrain[x][z][1], terrain[x][z][2]);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(terrain[x+1][z][0], terrain[x+1][z][1], terrain[x+1][z][2]);

        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(terrain[x][z+1][0], terrain[x][z+1][1], terrain[x][z+1][2]);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(terrain[x+1][z+1][0], terrain[x+1][z+1][1], terrain[x+1][z+1][2]);

    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are currently mapping your texture to each square. You need to have your glTexCoord2f change as you go over the terrain. Just divide the x and z coordinates by the width and height of your terrain in the for loop.

```
for (int z = 0; z < MAP_Z-1; z++)
{

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int x = 0; x < MAP_X-1; x++)
    {

        glTexCoord2f((float)x/(float)MAP_X, (float)z/(float)MAP_Z);
        ...
        ... // Other code with (x+1) and (z+1) in the glTexCoord2f
    }
}
```

Comment: You need some casts in there or else you're doing integer division.

Comment: I tried that way . I still getting tiles.. I am not sure i have made any mistake on my code. Is there any alternative way of doing ?

Comment: Can you show us an updated version of your attempt at using my solution? It should not produce tiling if done properly. Oh, and by the way, why are you using triangle strips? It would make more sense to use quads based on your code, I think.